# How to redirect from various ?page_id= to home page?

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I have a website where I need to 301 redirect all old pages that are incoming from old URLs like `/?page_id=261`, `/?page_id=204`, `/?page_id=2677` and so on to the main home page.

What would be a proper way of doing it? Will something like this in `.htaccess` work? I do not want to redirect all 404's - just these type of old links.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/?page_id=4&n=$1 https://www.example.com/
```

Comment: What's the `&n=$1` supposed to be referring to in your example code? There's no mention of this in your example URLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't match the query string using a mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directive. This directive matches against the URL-path only. You need to use mod_rewrite instead, with a condition that checks the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

For example, at the top of your `.htaccess` file, try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=\d+$
RewriteRule ^$ / [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The `QSD` flag (Apache 2.4) is required to remove the query string from the target URL.

However, from an SEO perspective, mass redirections like this will likely be seen as soft-404s by the search engines. You should try to redirect on a per page basis to the new URL. If the content no longer exists then return a 404.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it in a WordPressy way, the action hooks are the way to do so. Here's a self explanatory piece of code that will do the trick:

```
// We hook into the template_redirect action hook, which is the proper
// hook to be used for redirections
add_action('template_redirect','wpse339255_redirect_old_urls');

/**
 * Check whether the page_id query string has been set,
 * and if so, redirect the user to homepage
 */
function wpse339255_redirect_old_urls(){
    // Check if the page_id query string is set
    if( isset( $_GET['page_id'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['page_id'] ) ){
        // Do the redirect
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        die;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, this is also working fine. Thanks